# why isnt my .py running when I set up a http with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I ust the "python -m http.server" and this code

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8000


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_get(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

but when i go to localhost:8000, it shows me my files and if i navigate to the file, it goes into text instead of executing

Comment: The method's name is [`do_GET`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET), not `do_get`. Mind the capitalization.

Comment: You mention executing `python -m http.server`, which will launch a HTTP server, but then you also show a Python source file that will ALSO run a HTTP server if executed as a Python program.  These are two separate ways of running a HTTP server.  It sounds like maybe you think that because a file served by the standard Python HTTP server happens to be Python code, it's going to run that code as a Python script.  That's not how it works.  If the above code is in `myserver.py`, then run the command `python myserver.py` to run that code.  Then, as @SilvioMayolo says, rename `do_get` to `do_GET`.

Comment: Check out this simple tutorial:  https://pythonsansar.com/creating-simple-http-server-python/. Check out the last block of code in that tutorial and see that it looks a lot like the code in your question.